# Saving multiple images to isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I was trying to save multiple images into isolated storage by using creating a imageFolder in isolated storage and storing all my images inside.But it have an error so please anyone could help me solve the error or got other method way help me thanks.IF possible I would appreciate if you guys can show me your code that works. Actually my code would like to be under a button event handler.Thanks And the error is :Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

My Code :

```
         private void SaveToLocalStorage(string imageFolder, string imageFileName)
    {
        imageFileName = name.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(imageFileName);

        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (isf.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
        {
            isf.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
        }

        string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
        MessageBox.Show(filePath);
        using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            var bmp= new WriteableBitmap(inkCanvas, inkCanvas.RenderTransform);
            bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
      }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? do you get any errors? If so, what and where?

Comment: ya there is an error.Error: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. I could not solve . please help me

Comment: and at which line is this thrown? is the messagebox displayed?

Comment: the error was thrown at: using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(filePath)

Comment: and what is the value of `filePath` when it errors?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably want to be creating the directory if it DOESN'T exist, not if it does:

```
    if (!isf.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
    {
        isf.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
    }
```

Comment: what you mean? or could you kindly edit my code ? Really appreciate as i wan doing this for my assignment so i was kinda urgent.Thanks

Comment: I have, not in my answer I'm checking "if NOT directory exists"